# how to clear interval of timer based on the row where button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have basic understanding of javascript and jquery, but so far all i have done is client side validation and occasional ajax call to servlet. I need to display multiple countup timers(dynamically generated). 
My page will have many timers(each with their own start/pause/resume/stop buttons). I am able to start the timers individually, but unable to pause them individually.

Referred this link from stackoverflow.(http://jsfiddle.net/6nv3qy88/)
I created another setting `"pause:null"` in the above plugin.

```
    (function($) {
        $.fn.upCount = function(options, callback) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                startTime: null,
                resume: null,
                pause: false
            }, options);


            var container = this;
            globalContainer = container.parent().html();


            var currentDate = function() {
                // get client's current date
                var date = new Date();
                return date;
            };



            if(settings.startTime){
                resumeTimer(new Date(settings.startTime));
            }

            var original_date = currentDate();

            var paus = settings.pause;
            if(paus){
                alert("In settings.pause" + paus);
                var target_date = new Date('12/31/2014 12:00:00');
                paus = true;
            }else{
                var target_date = new Date('12/08/2015 14:55:00'); // Count up to this date
            }

            // Given a start time, lets set the timer
            function resumeTimer(startTime){
                alert('Resume Timer Needs to Start From StartTime  ' +startTime)
            }

            // Start the counter
            function countUp() {

                // Set our current date
                var current_date = currentDate(); 
                //alert("In countUp paus--" + paus);
                // difference of dates
                var difference = current_date - new Date(settings.startTime);

                if (current_date >= target_date) {
                    // stop timer
                    alert("In stop timer --" + target_date);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    interval = 0;
                    if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback();
                    return;
                }
//Code for Counting timer
            };

                interval = setInterval(countUp, 1000);



        };

    })(jQuery);
```

I am able to start the timers individually independent of each other based on rowIndex and start button id.

My code for starting timer:

```
    function startTimer(id, rowIndex){
    var startTimeId = 'id="list:'+rowIndex+':projectStartTime"';
        var y = $('['+startTimeId+']').text();
        //alert("value of y##" + y);

        if(y.length > 0){
            //$('#'+id).upCount({startTime: '12/04/2015 07:00:00', resume: true});
            $('#'+id).upCount({startTime: $('['+startTimeId+']').text()});
        }
      }
```

Above code helps me start multiple timers independently. But I am unable to pause the timers individually. If I click on any pause all timers stop. I use `clearInterval(interval)`
for pausing the timers.

pause function:

```
function pause(id, rowIndex){
    alert("In Function" + id);
    var timer = $('#'+id+' span').text();

    $('#'+id).upCount({startTime: '12/04/2015 07:00:00',pause: true});
}
```

**Help needed for:**

I would like to know how to clear interval only for the row from which the button is clicked i.e. the timer should pause once pause button is clicked.

JSF commandButton code:

```
<p:commandButton id="startBtn" action="#{timeBB.addTask}" value="Start"  style="align:center;" styleClass="button" onstart="startTimer(#{impl.timerId},#{rowIndex});">
       <f:param name="currentRow" value="#{impl.timerId}"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:commandButton id="pauseBtn" value="Pause" action="#{timeBB.pause}" style="align:center;" styleClass="buttonStyle" onstart="pause(#{impl.timerId},#{rowIndex});">
    <f:param name="currentProjectRowIndex" value="#{impl.timerId}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your posted code and logic seems all messed up. Can you provide MCVE?!

Comment: @razor: Please review you question. Formatting is not right. And please create an [mcve], way to much noise in there and lots of things missing (how is it jsf related? Where is the commandButton?)

Comment: @Kukeltje: Added JSF commandbutton.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, but please also try to achieve the M in [mcve]... And are you saying it works if you call 'startTimer(#{impl.timerId},#{rowIndex});' (or what is in the actual html) from the browser console?

Comment: I am able to call startTimer(). It is working fine. But pause() is not working.

Comment: `pause(#{impl.timerId},#{rowIndex})`; is also not working from the 'commandLine' in the browser console? if not, it is not JSF related at all... and again... [mcve]

Comment: I have updated my question. Hopefully, my query is clear.

Comment: if calling `pause(1,4) also does not work, it is **not** jsf related and you can remove the jsf tag and the jsf code.